# hibernate Error in creating SessionFactory object.javax/transaction/SystemException and NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception

I'm practicing on the hibernate but I got some error message that I could not figure that out yet.

console:

```
Error in creating SessionFactory object.javax/transaction/SystemException
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at screens.Screen_User.save(Screen_User.java:216)
at screens.Screen_User$1.actionPerformed(Screen_User.java:184)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

related class:

```
    package screens;

    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

    import javax.swing.JLabel;

    import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;

    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    import java.awt.Insets;

    import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
    import javax.swing.JButton;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
    import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
    import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

    import classes.Car_Rental;
    import classes.User;

    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.beans.Expression;
    import java.io.File;



public class Screen_User extends JPanel{
private JTextField txtUsername;
private JLabel lblName;
private JLabel lblSurname;
private JTextField txtSurname;
private JLabel lblGender;
private JTextField txtGender;
private JLabel lblAddress;
private JTextField txtAddress;
private JPasswordField passwordField;
private JTextField txtName;
private JLabel lblMailAddress;
private JTextField txtMailAddress;
private JButton btnKaydet;

User user= new User();


public Screen_User(){
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    JLabel lblUserName = new JLabel("Username:");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblUserName = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblUserName.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblUserName.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblUserName.gridx = 1;
    gbc_lblUserName.gridy = 1;
    add(lblUserName, gbc_lblUserName);

    txtUsername = new JTextField();
    txtUsername.setColumns(10);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_txtUsername = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_txtUsername.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_txtUsername.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_txtUsername.gridx = 2;
    gbc_txtUsername.gridy = 1;
    add(txtUsername, gbc_txtUsername);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblPassword = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblPassword.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblPassword.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblPassword.gridx = 1;
    gbc_lblPassword.gridy = 2;
    add(lblPassword, gbc_lblPassword);

    passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_passwordField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_passwordField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_passwordField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_passwordField.gridx = 2;
    gbc_passwordField.gridy = 2;
    add(passwordField, gbc_passwordField);

    lblName = new JLabel("Name:");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblName = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblName.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
    gbc_lblName.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblName.gridx = 1;
    gbc_lblName.gridy = 3;
    add(lblName, gbc_lblName);

    txtName = new JTextField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_txtName = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_txtName.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_txtName.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_txtName.gridx = 2;
    gbc_txtName.gridy = 3;
    add(txtName, gbc_txtName);
    txtName.setColumns(10);

    lblSurname = new JLabel("Surname:");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblSurname = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblSurname.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
    gbc_lblSurname.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblSurname.gridx = 1;
    gbc_lblSurname.gridy = 4;
    add(lblSurname, gbc_lblSurname);

    txtSurname = new JTextField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_txtSurname = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_txtSurname.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_txtSurname.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_txtSurname.gridx = 2;
    gbc_txtSurname.gridy = 4;
    add(txtSurname, gbc_txtSurname);
    txtSurname.setColumns(10);

    lblGender = new JLabel("Gender:");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblGender = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblGender.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblGender.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblGender.gridx = 1;
    gbc_lblGender.gridy = 5;
    add(lblGender, gbc_lblGender);

    txtGender = new JTextField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_txtGender = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_txtGender.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_txtGender.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_txtGender.gridx = 2;
    gbc_txtGender.gridy = 5;
    add(txtGender, gbc_txtGender);
    txtGender.setColumns(10);

    lblAddress = new JLabel("Address:");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblAddress = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblAddress.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblAddress.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblAddress.gridx = 1;
    gbc_lblAddress.gridy = 6;
    add(lblAddress, gbc_lblAddress);

    txtAddress = new JTextField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_txtAddress = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_txtAddress.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_txtAddress.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_txtAddress.gridx = 2;
    gbc_txtAddress.gridy = 6;
    add(txtAddress, gbc_txtAddress);
    txtAddress.setColumns(10);

    lblMailAddress = new JLabel("Mail address:");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblMailAddress = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblMailAddress.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_lblMailAddress.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblMailAddress.gridx = 1;
    gbc_lblMailAddress.gridy = 7;
    add(lblMailAddress, gbc_lblMailAddress);

    txtMailAddress = new JTextField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_txtMailAddress = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_txtMailAddress.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gbc_txtMailAddress.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_txtMailAddress.gridx = 2;
    gbc_txtMailAddress.gridy = 7;
    add(txtMailAddress, gbc_txtMailAddress);
    txtMailAddress.setColumns(10);

    btnKaydet = new JButton("Kaydet");
    btnKaydet.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            save();
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnKaydet = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnKaydet.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_btnKaydet.gridx = 1;
    gbc_btnKaydet.gridy = 9;
    add(btnKaydet, gbc_btnKaydet);
    }

public void save(){
    Session sess = null;
    Transaction tran = null;

    try{

        SessionFactory sessFact = createSessionFactory();
        sess = sessFact.openSession();
        tran = sess.beginTransaction();
        initUser();
        sess.save(user);
        tran.commit();

    }
  catch (Throwable e) {
        System.err.println("Error in creating SessionFactory object." 
            + e.getMessage());
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
    }
    finally{
        sess.close();
    }
}
    public void initUser(){
        user.setAddress(txtAddress.toString());
        user.setGender(txtGender.toString());
        user.setMail_address(txtMailAddress.toString());
        user.setName(txtName.toString());
        user.setPassword(passwordField.toString());
        user.setSurname(txtSurname.toString());
        user.setUsername(txtUsername.toString());
    }

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
       // Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        //configuration.configure();
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\workspace\\Hotel\\src\\hibernate"));
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-configuration>
       <session-factory>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect">
          org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
          com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
       </property>

       <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
       <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
          jdbc:mysql://localhost/hotel
       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
          root
       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
          root123
       </property>

       <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
       <mapping resource="Hotel.hbm.xml"/>
       <mapping resource="Car_Rental.hbm.xml"/>
       <mapping resource="Hotel_Reservation.xml"/>
       <mapping resource="Ticket_Reservation.hbm.xml"/>
       <mapping resource="Tour_Reservation.hbm.xml"/>
       <mapping resource="Touristic_Place.hbm.xml"/>
       <mapping resource="User.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

I'm looking for solution for 6 hour but I have not found any. hopefully I could solve this issue soon. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your path of the file is wrong

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\workspace\\Hotel\\src\\hibernate"));
```

Should be

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\workspace\\Hotel\\src\\hibernate.cfg.xml"));
                                                                                                                 ---------^
```

More over you must give a relative path to your application. Otherwise you need to change this path while deploying.

Comment: I tryed that but no progress. 
I also tryed this 
 // Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
 //configuration.configure();
before file path but its not working too